# lxml escapes &#xA; to \n during parsing document

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have very specific use case where I have to parse xml from client and than calculate checksum from a particular element. And because of that text in elements must be intact.

Inside the obtained document from client represents new line as `"&#xA;"` and for some reason it is converted to `\n` in python. Please take a note that the document in this particular example was simplied.

```
from lxml.etree import tostring, fromstring
import hashlib

document = "<root><note><body>Some text, text &#xA;text text text</body></note></root>"
tree = fromstring(document)
# I retrieve the element for which I need to calculate checksum
body_element =tree.find("note/body")
tostring(body_element)
```

output:

```
b'<body>Some text, text \ntext text text</body>'
```

Now I calculate the checksum:

```
hashlib.sha256(tostring(body_element)).hexdigest()
```

output:

```
907730861e15fdfb90674400024f349676fda03eb85fcc10102dbf1eb6194f4b
```

It is different from what do the client on it ends and I equivalent of this:

```
hashlib.sha256(b"<body>Some text, text &#xA;text text text</body>").hexdigest()
```

which is equal to:

```
9f7cb6989df55572968be655fb86e461c257a74f8cc40019d1315a5c10978cd8
```

I want to prevent conversion of text in elements. Because the client calculated the checksum for `<body>Some text, text &#xA;text text text</body>` and this leads to a conflict with the checksum that I calculate where `&#xA;` is replaced with `\n`

How should I approach this? I tried to change encoding but It did not help.

I also though about replacing `&#xA;` with another character before looking for the element and replacing it back just before calculating the checksum but because the obtained document might have some other unexpected characters It looks like a not complete solution and might cause another problems.

Comment: Work with the variable `document` instead of `body_element`. Don't put `<note>` around the original data

Comment: @ThomasWeller sorry but as I mention I have to calculate checksum for body_element not a document. Please read my question again.

Comment: I fixed the example

Comment: It can be interpreted now, but it has no output. You still didn't run your own code

Comment: `&#xA;`, `&#10;` and `\n` are the same [characters since XML 1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charsets). That's why the parser can replace one by the other.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I fixed the example code I also included more information why this is so important not to replace the &#xA; with \n. Please let me know if it is clear now.

Comment: It's still not clear what your code gets. Does it get a string or does it get an XML Element from Etree? Do you call `fromString()` or did someone else call `fromString()` already?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239400/discussion-between-przemek-and-thomas-weller).

Comment: If your checksumming algorithm treats `&#xa;` differently from a regular newline (or from `&#x10;` for that matter) then it is broken.